# Fetch nodes according to parents and two way relations

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher, nodes, relationship

I have to solve some problem with "complex" queries in Cypher. Maybe this is simple for an expert but I am a complete newbie.

With these relations, I need to know if given a list of items and a particular item, I could use it.
Some items enables to use other items, and some items need (required) items.

[items_relations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iU4wO.png)

Examples (see image):

- If I have Item A, could I use Item B? Yes
- If I have Item B, could I use Item D? Yes
- If I have Item B, could I use Item E? No, because Item C is also requerid.
- If I have Item A and B, could I use Item E? No, because Item C is also requerid.
- If I have Item A and B and C, could I use Item E? Yes.

I know my list of items, not empty, ex: ['Item A', 'Item B']
and the item I need, ex: 'Item D'

Return can be a Boolen or the needed item.

The graph can be created with this:

```
MERGE (n:Item {name: 'Item A' });
MERGE (n:Item {name: 'Item B' });
MERGE (n:Item {name: 'Item C' });
MERGE (n:Item {name: 'Item D' });
MERGE (n:Item {name: 'Item E' });

MATCH (it: Item { name: 'Item A' })
  MATCH (otherIt: Item { name: 'Item B' })
  MERGE (it)-[:Enables]->(otherIt);

MATCH (it: Item { name: 'Item A' })
  MATCH (otherIt: Item { name: 'Item C' })
  MERGE (it)-[:Enables]->(otherIt);

MATCH (it: Item { name: 'Item B' })
  MATCH (otherIt: Item { name: 'Item D' })
  MERGE (it)-[:Enables]->(otherIt);

MATCH (it: Item { name: 'Item B' })
  MATCH (otherIt: Item { name: 'Item E' })
  MERGE (it)-[:Enables]->(otherIt);

MATCH (it: Item { name: 'Item C' })
  MATCH (otherIt: Item { name: 'Item E' })
  MERGE (it)-[:Enables]->(otherIt);

MATCH (it: Item {name: 'Item B'})
 MATCH (req: Item {name: 'Item E'})
 MERGE (req)-[:Requires]->(it);

MATCH (it: Item {name: 'Item C'})
 MATCH (req: Item {name: 'Item E'})
 MERGE (req)-[:Requires]->(it);
```

Answer (score 0):

ok this is hands down ugly :)  basically we ensure that all items required ( up the tree from the item we want to use ) and all the items that enable the item we want to user ( also up the tree ) are available within the list of items we have.    is the count is zero then we can not use this item.

hope if this is not your exact solution then it gets you some new ideas :)

( on a side note this is something i much rather not solve in cypher but in Java as a procedure ( my 2 cents anyway  ) )

```
match (i:Item)
where i.name in ['Item A','Item B','Item C']
with collect (distinct i) as myItems

match (canIUseThis:Item{name:'Item E'})
WITH myItems, canIUseThis

match (canIUseThis)<-[:Enables *1..]-(x)
WITH myItems, canIUseThis, COLLECT(DISTINCT x) as enablers

match (canIUseThis)-[:Requires *1..]->(y)
WITH myItems, canIUseThis, enablers, COLLECT(DISTINCT y) as reqs

match (canIUseThis)
where all(x in reqs where x in myItems)  and all (x in enablers where x in myItems)
return count(*)
```